# Spring MVC Request mapping, can this be dynamic/configurable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

With Spring MVC, I know how you set the `RequestMapping` in every controller and method/action.

But what if I wanted this to be configurable, so for example I the following controllers:

```
BlogController 
 - with methods for listing blogs entries, single entry, new, update, etc.
ArticleController
 - with methods for listing articles entries, single entry, new, update, etc.
```

Now in my application, the administrator can setup 2 blogs for the webiste, and 1 article section so the urls would be like:

```
www.example.com/article_section1/ - uses ArticleController
www.example.com/blog1/ - uses BlogController
www.example.com/blog2/ - uses BlogController
```

Maybe after a while the administrator wants another article section, so they just configure that with a new section like:

```
www.example.com/article_section2/
```

**This has to work dynamically/on-the-fly without having to restart the application of course.**

My question is only concerned with how I will handle url mappings to my controllers.

How would this be possible with Spring MVC?

I only know how to map urls to controllers using `@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")` at the controller or method level, but this makes the url mappings fixed and not configurable like how I want it.

**Update:**

I will be storing the paths in the database, and with the mapping to the type of controller so like:

```
path                  controller
/article_section1/    article
/blog1/               blog
/blog2/               blog
..
```

With the above information, how could I dispatch the request to the correct controller?

Again, not looking to reload/redeploy, and I realize this will require more work but its in the spec :)

Comment: How did you end up implementing this? I am in a similar situation.

Answer (score 5):

Would this sort of URL mapping work for you?

```
www.example.com/blog/1/
www.example.com/blog/2/
```

If yes, then that's easy: Spring 3 supports path variables: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-advanced

Alternatively, you can create a generic request mapping and your own sub-dispatcher that reads a config file, but I think that's probably more work than it's worth.

Comment: I want complete control over the url, I know about path variables thanks. Actually I am going to read the paths from the database, and then forward requests somehow to the correct controller, but not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

Truly changing the request mappings at runtime might be hard (and not really recommended, since small errors can easily occur). If you still wish to do it, perhaps JRebel, and more specificly LiveRebel can be interesting for live redeployment of code and configuration.

Otherwise, like other posts suggested, RequestMappings supports wildcards, the limits of this should be clear after a quick read of the official documentation.

Comment: no I want complete control over the url, so this won't work, and I don't want to reload/redeploy any code.  was hoping I could somehow forward the request to the correct controller somehow.

Comment: Writing your own HandlerMapping might be interesting http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html

Comment: thanks for that link, this seems to be the direction I will have to take given the requirements.

Comment: What's the name of the handlermapping that picks up annotations @RequestMapping, would that be simple?

Comment: JRebel supports Spring annotations so if you change @RequestMapping value, it the mapping will be reconfigured on the fly. As well as adding new beans, conponents, services, etc

Comment: @AntonArhipov Personally, I would't use JRebel in a production environment (though perhaps LiveRebel is interesting, haven't tried it out). The reloading doesn't feel 100% secure, since some classes state might break. For example, entity managers in my EJBs are sometimes set to null after a reload, breaking my applikation.

Comment: @RasmusFranke You can't use JRebel in production, it is even the license restriction. Besides, one has to be insane to map the IDE to production app :)

Comment: @AntonArhipov ahha, well said!

Answer (score 1):

Try using with @RequestMapping wild cards as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/article_section*/"}
public void getArticle(....){
//TODO implementation
}

@RequestMapping(value="/blog*/"}
public void getBlog(....){
//TODO implementation
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Also another solution might be to create a custom annotation that holds the already defined path on the `@RequestMapping` and also the new one to apply, let's say `@ApiRestController`.

Then, before the Spring context loads, the `@Controller` classes can be changed to have their annotation values changed at runtime by the new one (with the desired path). By doing this, Spring will load the enhanced request mapping and not the default one.

Created a small project to exemplify this for someone that needs this in the future https://gitlab.com/jdiasamaro/spring-api-rest-controllers.

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but reviewing the code, this might actually solve a rather unique problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

doesn't this work?
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld*")