# How to get path inside @GetMapping from other service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I have a rest controller with @GetMapping annotation for mapping HTTP requests onto specific handler methods:

```
@RestController
class Handler(){
    @GetMapping(path = ["method"])
    fun handlerMethod(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Also I have email service where I need to send some email with link to my endpoint (in that case http://host/method)

```
@Service
class EmailService(val config: Config){

    fun sendEmail(){
        // send "config.baseUrl/${getMethodPath()}"
    }

    fun getMethodPath(){
        //todo
    }
}
```

Here I get base url from configuration (http://host). Is there any way to get path attribute in EmailService from Handler's @GetMapping for build link to my service?

Comment: Maybe this would be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710307/spring-mvc-request-mapping-can-this-be-dynamic-configurable

Answer (score 1):

you can get the request bound to the current thread by `RequestContextHolder`.

`((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()`

The above code will get the `HttpServletRequest` and then you can use `[HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()][1]` to get the `path` of the URL

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path information from HttpServletRequest object. Please check this:

[How to get request URL in Spring Boot RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710557/how-to-get-request-url-in-spring-boot-restcontroller)

If you are not getting exact path, check this for different approaches to get paths:
[What's the difference between getRequestURI and getPathInfo methods in HttpServletRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931323/whats-the-difference-between-getrequesturi-and-getpathinfo-methods-in-httpservl)

Answer (score 0):

Spring has support for doing just this task. In your controller method, pass a parameter of type `UriComponentsBuilder`. This builder will have all the information about the current request routing (hostname, port, path, etc.). You can then use `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` to have Spring construct the link that you need (Java, but it should be equivalent in Kotlin):

```
MvcUriComponentsBuilder.relativeTo(builderParameter)
    .fromMethod(Handler.class, "method")
```